# Vim search and replace positional arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, vim, pattern-matching

I am trying to replace positional arguments with variables in my bash script using Vim's substitute `:s`command.

**Example:**
I would like to replace the following text in a bash script:

```
python3 mymodule.py --dataversion $1
```

with:

```
python3 mymodule.py --dataversion "${DATAVERSION}"
```

I have tried `:s/\$1/"${DATAVERSION}"` resulting in `E486: Pattern not found: $1`.

When I search the pattern instead of substituting, `/\$1`, the instances are detected. Why is this pattern different in Vim's search and susbstitute commands?

Comment: your vim command will only do the replacement on the current line -- prepend it a `%` if you want to do the search and replace in the whole file.

Comment: What mosvy said, also, you don't have to escape the `$` as it is not the last character in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

When you search, Vim will automatically consider the entire buffer (provided you haven't disabled the [`'wrapscan'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wrapscan%27) option - then it would only search until the end). Your `:substitute` command only considers the *current line*, as you've left out the [`:help :range`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange), and this command (like most others) defaults to the current line only. To cover the entire buffer for your substitution, just prepend `%`, which is an abbreviation for `1,$`:

```
:%s/\$1/"${DATAVERSION}"
```

Also, if there were multiple occurrences of `$1` in a line, only the first one would be replaced. Append `/g` for a global substitution.

As mentioned in the comments, the `$` does not need to be escaped (it only has special meaning at the end of the pattern), but it's fine to escape it, too (and avoids some thinking).